# Postgresql -- All else equal, is querying for (small) integer or float values faster than querying for (small) string values?

Tags: sql, string, performance, postgresql, integer

I'm about to mark maybe 100,000 records retroactively/posthoc-wise with category-indicating string or integer values. There are more to come. The categories to be marked by this column reflect a scalar continuum of different category types, going anywhere from "looser" to "tighter" essentially. I was thinking about using string values though, instead of integers, in case one day I come back to it and not know what means what.

So that's the reasoning for using strings, readability.

But I'll be relying on these columns pretty significantly, selecting swaths of records based off this criteria.

Obviously whatever it is I'm going to put an index on it, but with an index, I'm not sure how much faster querying on integers is than using strings. I've noticed the speediness of using booleans, and can reasonably assume small integers can be queried on more quickly than strings based off this.

I've been pondering this trade off for some time now so thought I'd fire off a question. Thanks

Comment: Use small integers, it will improve performance in large batch processing.  The easy fix for readability is to simply add a new config table that maps the integers to the string representations...

Comment: Only add complexity to your application if you really need it. 100,000 records is not much and the gain in speed wont be really big (specially if you will need to map the integers to strings back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really a string representing some ordered level between "looser" and "tighter", consider using an enum:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html

That way, you'll get the best of both worlds.

One tiny note, though: ideally, make sure you nail all possible values in advance. Changing an enum is of course possible, but doing so adds an extra lookup and sort step internally (on a 32-bit float field) when the order of its numeric representation (its oid, which is a 32-bit integer) no longer matches its final order. (The performance difference is minor, but one to keep in mind should your data ever grow to billions of rows. And, again: it only applies when you alter the order of an existing enum.)

Regarding the second part of your question, sorting small integers (16-bit) is, in my own admittedly limited testing from a few years back, a bit slower than normal integers (32-bit). I imagine it's because they're manipulated as 32-bit integers anyway. And sorting or querying integers, as in the case of enums, is faster than sorting arbitrary strings. Ergo, use enums if you don't need the flexibility of adding arbitrary values down thhe road: they'll give you the best of each world.